# Shunt Current measurement noise

Tags: ac, adc, noise, high-voltage, signal-integrity

I was measuring current through shunt method. below is the SCH and waveform captured. PB5-AI will to ADC which has max 1 Volt limit.

[image]

Waveform capture across R30

[image]

So why this much noise on output waveform, and when i reduce time scale of same waveform i observe spike on waveform(see picture), I tried to add 0.1uf cap across R30, but not helped. any suggestion 
I doubt with this much noise my ADC will not capture it.

Comment: Did you measure how much noise is there on the 3.4 V supply output?

Comment: Only other things I see is that C21 is way too small to give low impedance at 50 Hz, and the non-inverting input is probably going below "ground" in the positive half cycle of the line voltage.

Comment: I wil measure it now, Also i will try to increase C21 to 1uF.

Comment: You've shown a 'L' symbol connected to a ground symbol. That sort of connection will last for only a few mS while the fuse or breaker opens the circuit. Please correct your circuit diagram by using different symbols for different nodes.

Comment: No, L (Line) is correct because its connected to line, its non isolated supply, PS working fine. Below link of PS circuit (page 5) http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/328/LinkSwitch-TN2_family_datasheet-1036065.pdf

Comment: You also need a 22 pF capacitor in parallel with R4.  A low pass filter capacitor in parallel with R30 will assist with HF noise reduction.  (Try 10 \$\mu\$F :-)

Comment: I measure the noise on power supply line, it has the same pattern as noise shown in 2nd waveform above. now task is to reduce noise form power supply. Power supply reference circuit taken form (page 5)of mouser.com/ds/2/328/LinkSwitch-TN2_family_datasheet-1036065.‌​pdf .

Answer (score 3):

Your circuit there is very dangerous and will not work correctly.

You are applying 240V to R6 and R22 which will cause the input of the amplifier to go way outside its common mode range.

How are you connecting the scope to the circuit? Generally scopes are grounded to the AC ground so the ground clip on the probe will be connected to the AC ground.  That is not the same as neutral and will have noise on it relative to neutral.

You say you are using a "non-isolated" supply.  Why?

The better way to do the current sensing is to use a [current transformer](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transformer/current-transformer.html) - this will be safer and provide isolation.

Current transformers might have a primary with just one turn and a secondary with 1000 turns - this will give a ratio of 1:1000.  So 1 Amp in the primary results in 1mA in the secondary - if you then put a 1 Kilohm resistor on the secondary (usually referred to a as burden resistor) it will give 1V output for 1Amp in the primary.

Comment: Reason is Cost , need to reduce cost very very low. Also R6 and R22 will not have 240V because L (line) is connected to GND itself. So Voltage on R6 and R22 will not have more than drop across R8.

Comment: OK.  How are you connecting to your scope?  Is it an isolated oscilloscope?

Comment: by bypassing scope earth terminal. since i do not have non isolated scope and any differential probe.

Comment: Do you mean you have isolated the scope ground from AC ground? Apart from anything else that is very dangerous. What do you see if you put the the scope probe and the scope ground clip at the grounded end of R30 - you should see nothing but you may not.

Comment: Yes I have isolated the scope ground terminal, since i have no other option, you mean both terminal of probe on same point (ground of R30), I didn't check yet , but i m sure i will see lot of noise that is coming form AC mains. I will check